# Why was Raine's bomb easier to disarm than Omar's and Donowitz's?

Tags: plot-explanation, inglourious-basterds

During the end of *Inglourious Basterds*, why is it not possible to remove the bombs from Omar and Donowitz without exploding them, when they easily disarm/remove Raine's?

> There ain't no way you gonna take them boys without setting off them bombs.

Is there anything I am not seeing?

Comment: Raine is clearly as good at setting explosives as he is at speaking Italian ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implication is not that the bombs are hard to disarm, but that Omar and Donowitz would explode the bombs rather than surrender. Raine was taken by surprise and thus had no chance to explode his bomb (not that he would want to anyway) because he was in the lobby. It would be much harder to take them by surprise in the theater because they are surrounded by sitting people and the sight of activity or weapons or anything else that would be involved in subduing Omar and Donowitz would result in them exploding the bombs before they could be captured.